# Parsing through edges in NetworkX graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I'm trying to get edges that have a certain attribute from a graph without using get_edge_attributes() function. I need a more flexible way of doing it. I can get node attributes but since I'm new at python edges seem difficult

```
G = nx.read_graphml("test.graphml")

for n in G:
  print "%s\t%s" %(n, G.node[n].get(attr))

for (s,d) in G:       # and here is my problem
  print "%s->%s\t%s" %(s, d, G.edge[s][d].get(attr))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the G.edges() or G.edges_iter() methods to loop over all of the graph edges.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2,weight=7)

In [4]: G.add_edge(2,3,weight=10)

In [5]: for u,v,a in G.edges(data=True):
    print u,v,a
   ...:     
1 2 {'weight': 7}
2 3 {'weight': 10}
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is now slightly outdated: the `edges_iter` method is deprecated.

The `edges` attribute [can be used as a method or a property](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html#networkx.Graph.edges). (It’s actually an `EdgeView` value, which is iterable, and callable)

Now you can iterate over all edges this way:

```py
for u,v in G.edges:
    print(u,v)
```

or, like before, with data

```py
for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True):
    print(f"({u}, {v}) {d=}")
```